# Float a navbar <li> element to right

Tags: html, css

i need to float my a elements inside a li tag to the right. Here below i have attached HTML and CSS file please have a look. I need a navbar with elements floated to left.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div.nav {
  background-color: #009866;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to use a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). You can align your items to the right with `justify-content`

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div.nav {
  background-color: #009866;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, :)

Comment: @Syed, which system did you choose? `flex` or `float`?

Comment: i used flex one.  very easy to understand and use. thanks to @Gerard

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I didn't read your code, But why `float`? you can use `flex` instead of `float`. it is really easy to understand, and `float` layout with `display: block` wrapper and children need a complex concept that name is `clearfix`. it is so hard to understand.

Write your codes like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Web Project</title>
    <style>
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            direction: rtl;
        }

        .navbar {
            list-style-type: none;
            background-color: #009866;
            padding:10px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: center;
        }
        li {
            margin: 0 10px;
        }
        li:first-child {
            margin-right: 0;
        }
        li:last-child {
            margin-left: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

But if you insist on using `float`, ok, use the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Web Project</title>
    <style>
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            direction: rtl;
        }

        .clearfix:after {
            content:'';
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }

        .navbar {
            list-style-type: none;
            background-color: #009866;
            padding:10px;
            display: block;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: center;
        }
        li {
            margin: 0 10px;
            display: inline-block;
            float: right;
        }
        li:first-child {
            margin-right: 0;
        }
        li:last-child {
            margin-left: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <ul class="navbar clearfix">
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope these codes help you.

Comment: your answer works fine but its lengthy while the other one i find very easy.